# Recording audio - too low loudness differences

Tags: audio, microphone, speech, recording

I am trying to record sounds from the microphone when there's something happening (be it somebody talking or just moving things around - basically anything that isn't just random noise)

Up until now, my approach has been to record for 1-2 seconds, check if the recording passes the test for "anything happening", if so, I could record for as long as the new 1-2 second recordings didn't pass the test.

Now my problem here is the test. What I am doing now is basically setting a threshold, so it basically looks like this:

```
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < SAMPLE_RATE * NUM_SECONDS; i++) {
    if(buffer[i] > threshold)
        return true;
}
return false;
```

All was working nice and sound until I've tested the application on a laptop with a very weak microphone. The problem is that on a decent built in microphone, the "loudness" (or more like, sample value) of background noise (nothing happening, basically) equals to ~130, and when you speak, depending on how far you are from the microphone, the values go up to 160-135 (close-far). But there is a difference, and you can cross the threshold.

The thing is, that with the weak microphone the values don't seem to change. It stays at 130 (Althrough it **might** be moving by one point now and then).

Now, my guess would be that I lack precision. But I'm recording in 16 bits. Is it even possible to record in more than 16 bits? (for example, floats or doubles)
You can hear the weak microphone user when he's talking on skype, for example, so I pretty much think that it's a precision issue (weak microphone has a hard time detecting sounds, so I suppose that the default noise value is 130, and it goes up to something like 130.2 when somebody's talking)

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the type of your sample values (what does 130 mean to us)? You may or may not be observing normal behavior. Cheap microphones suffer poor dynamic range/poor SNR and you cannot hard-code a gate threshold. It must be calibrated by the user manually or detected by analysis.

Comment: I record in 16 bits, therefore a sample is a 16 bit integer (int16_t). I'm not hardcoding the gate - it's to be adjusted by the user. Still, somehow you can hear the speech even when the values are nearly just the same (130-131). I suppose that has something to do with how sound works, and it cannot be easily detected? (instead of setting a threshold, maybe I should look for the values being offset a lot? (130,131,131,130,130,131) for sound to record, (130,130,130,130,130...) for no sound to record?

Comment: Unless the microphone gain setting is very low you should be detecting much larger values. 16-bit is `-32768` to `+32767`. Even a poor microphone should have higher SNR when amplified. It is possible to hear quiet signal through high noise but the SNR you have described would be unusually poor. You should check for bugs as well because the numbers you are detecting may be incorrect.

Comment: The values on my PC range from 140 to 190 (built in mic). Not quite sure if I can be possibly doing something wrong. After all, everything works and the values do change when speaking. Not quite certain here, but I suppose this code is OK? http://pastebin.com/83Ux6dJb It enables me to reuse the buffer and start recording again after 2 seconds of each recording. Other than that, not quite sure what could be wrong. I guess I should try detecting the sound by noise level.

Comment: The sound level goes up to 2367 when talking like 1 cm from the built in mic.

Comment: It could be the mic just needs a boost (prior to sampling). Some mics are like that. In general you don't need to prepare software for this type of unusual scenario. People with bad mics will need to disable this feature. If it is the only mic you have for testing it will hinder development. If the mic is the problem there is not an elegant way to program around it.